# Visual studio 2019- Python

Tags: python, visual-studio

Is there a recommended way to use Python in Visual Studio? I worked so far with C/C++ and I already have Visual Studio; however, when trying to open a Python project I get this message:

[image]

What is the best way to use Python in Visual Studio?

Or it's better to use other workspace for python ?

Answer (score 1):

This should guide you through setting up python interpreters for VS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/installing-python-interpreters?view=vs-2019

However, with that said, visual studio is designed for C/C# etc. and python is quite a different language, if you like visual studio I would suggest either trying PyCharm (By Jetbrains, there is a free version available) or Visual Studio Code.

Personally I use VS Code, but that's just personal preference.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on you, you can work with Visual Studio, you just need to install everything that is required to support Python, and you can just search on YouTube `how to use Python in Visual Studio` and just follow a tutorial and everything should work fine.

I personally prefer to program in PyCharm, it is very recommended IDE for Python.

Answer (score 0):

Visual Studio is one of the best IDE out there. And your error :

> they didn't find the interpreter

is pretty much self explanatory.

It can be due to the fact you didn't install python or maybe your path is not set. You can go through this [link](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial#_install-a-python-interpreter) which may help you.